# Input power calculation of NE5534 as a headphone amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a simple audio amplifier design based on OP-AMP NE5534.
The maximum output (short circuit) current spec'ed in the datasheet is 38mA.
If my supply input rails are + and - 12v, can I safely assume that I can use a boost converter like [the LM5001](http://www.ti.com/tool/lownoisesplitrailnoniso-boost-ref) as below?

> Features
>   Max 5.5V        40 mA     40 mA   The performance of the reference design
>   is as follows:
>
> 5V Input
>   +/- 12V Outputs Over 40 mA Output Current Low Ripple Noise for split rail analog circuits (< 2 mV p-p) Small Size ~1" x 1" The performance
>   of the reference design is as follows:
>
> 5V Input
>   +/- 12V Outputs Over 40 mA Output Current Low Ripple Noise for split rail analog circuits (< 2 mV p-p) Small Size ~1" x 1"

The critical numbers I see are 40mA on both -/+ rail, which is more than the maximum short-circuited current requirement of the op-amp.

I would like to get this confirmed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The NE5534 (assuming [TI's](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sa5534.pdf)) has a *typical output* s.c. current of 38mA. The max is unspecified in the datasheet and could well be higher. (Nor does that mean that's the current chip will draw in when you short its output.)

My own practical experience with TI's NE553**2** is that some samples can well dish out the max 60mA, which [their datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532.pdf) says they can; typical value for TI's NE5532 is also 38mA for s.c. current. (Also beware that the mininum guaranteed for NE5532 is only 10mA; no promises are made for NE5534. So don't bet your house you'll get 38mA out of a NE5534.) It's not clear from your question if you expect to max out the opamp output current (or not) in your design. But if you do, you should use a higher-rated regulator.

Also you need to add the quiescent current to the output current to estimate what the chip will draw. For NE5534 it's a typical 4mA and a max of 8mA. (As an aside, the quiescent current numbers for NE5532 are exactly twice those, which is what you'd expect for a dual package.) So, even at typical values you'd pushing the supply you've chosen slightly over its max limit (38+4=42mA).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I plan to use the audio amp with a pair of Sennheiser HD449 (32ohm). Simply put, I just want to comfortably power the op-amp to drive these phones. I have no clue how much current it will be drawing =(. Perhaps I should figure that out first.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should really be "Input power calculation for..." as what you are really concerned with is how much current you need to supply from the PSU.

The 38mA value you quote is a typical value so it could be significantly more than that.

However, in your application as a headphone amplifier with an AC audio signal you won't get the short circuit current continuously as it will alternate between the +12V and -12V supply.

In addition to the capability of the device the supply current will be defined by the load that is being driven.

What headphone impedance are you intending to drive?

Are there one or two channels?

Comment: thanks I updated the title. I plan to drive portable headphones(?). The ones you can buy from say, Amazon. I have a pair of Sennheiser HD449 (32 ohm), which I plan to use the amp with. And I am using NE5534 per channel.

Comment: @b1gtuna: Those HD449 are 32Ω. Assuming you'll be pushing 2V (not 12V) peaks through them (which will be pretty loud, trust me), you'd be trying to get 62mA from the NE5532, enough to make them distort a lot. I actually wonder why you think you need +/-12 V supply for this (low impedance) application. Note that almost anything in the NE5532/NE5534 datasheets (noise, distortion) is spec'ed for 600Ω loads (20x what you have here)...

Comment: @RespawnedFluff ya I seem to lack some basic understanding. I was forgetting the loudness was a function of the output voltage. With 2V peak-to-peak, 62mA is more than the example boost circuit can provide. It's also larger than the specified maximum short-circuit current of NE5534. I guess I have to prove even smaller peak-to-peak voltage (1.3v ~= 32ohm x 42mA).